# Move files from one user account to another in OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, file-management

How can I move files from user account to another in OS X 10.6.8?

Every time I attempt access another users contents eg images, music, and the like. It keeps telling I don't have permission to view the contents.

What do I do to move the files from one user account to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What tapped-out proposed is a good way to move one time the files, but if what you want is to gain access, you can use this:

Say your users are Foo and Bar, you are Foo and you want access to Bar's file:
login as Bar, go in finder and right click the folder you want access to. Click Get Info. At the bottom, you should see this:

[image: Sharing and Permission]

You can use the plus(+) at the bottom left to add Foo to the permission of the folder. When you do so, give him Read & Write permission and there you go. You should be able to go back as Foo and fully access this precise folder in the system and do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have administrator access:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. `sudo cp -r /Users/foo/bar ~`

This copies folder `bar` from user `foo` into your home directory as the superuser (hence `sudo`).